# Is this the way Constructor in Java allocates memory?

Tags: java

Default constructor is automatically called after an object is created.

But in Java when we allocate memory using new operator i.e. `classname obj = new classname();`  the constructor is automatically invoked **before new allocates memory** to the class member's.

The allocation starts after the class comes into physical existence but if new operator completes its process after default constructor is called, then how default constructor actually do so as the class has not come into physical existence?

Can someone explain me the same using a clear example?

Comment: If the memory was allocated after the constructor was called, what memory would the constructor be working on?

Answer (score 11):

The process is basically:

- Memory is allocated
- Execution goes *up* the constructor chain (i.e. all the `this` / `super` calls to other constructors) each level evaluating any arguments to the level above, but that's all
- Execution goes *down* the constructor chain for the actual constructor bodies. So the body of the `java.lang.Object` constructor is executed first, then the direct subclass, etc. This is also when variable initializers are executed. (Prior to this, the variables have their default values of null etc.)
- The reference is returned to whoever called `new`

The idea of a default constructor has no meaning at execution time. It's just a parameterless constructor which calls `super()` as far as the JVM is concerned.

The business about the constructor chain is exactly the same as it would be if these were methods with a first line which just chains to the next constructor along; it's just a stack of calls.

Comment: Being pedantic, the class will be loaded as required. Not sure if this is before or after the memory is allocated. BTW Allocating the memory and calling the constructor are separate byte code instruction.

Comment: @Peter: Class loading is somewhat separate from creating an instance, really - in particular you may call a static method before creating any instances. However, I take your point about the memory allocation and the constructor call. I wasn't aware of that before.

Answer (score 3):

> But in Java when we allocate memory using new operator i.e. classname obj=new classname(); the constructor is automatically invoked before new allocates memory to the class member's.

That is incorrect.  The constructor is invoked *after* memory has been allocated.

@Jon Skeet's answer explains clearly the sequence of events that occur during object creation.

You may be confused by the fact that the constructors may well cause further objects to be allocated; e.g. during the execution of the declaration initializers.  But these objects don't occupy memory in the original object; i.e. the object we are constructing.

---

If you want a *definitive* specification of what happens when an object is created, read the Java Language Specification - in particular [JLS 12.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5).

Comment: I have read this in Complete reference of Java seventh editon

Comment: I think you have **misread** the text.  If you think otherwise, please quote the exact section of text that you are believe says that.

Comment: Text from the book is : Constructor is automatically called immediately after the object is created, but before the new operator completes.

Comment: @Vibhakar - the text book is correct.  It is your summary of what the textbook says that is incorrect.  The phrase "after the object is created" means after the memory for the object has been allocated.

Comment: @Vibhakar - And further, "the new operator completes" refers to the entire process laid out by Jon Skeet of which calling the constructors is a part. Therefore it must happen before the end. Please accept some answers before asking more questions, or people will be less inclined to answer you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider an example like

```
classname obj = new classname();
```

`classname obj` initialize the object and `new classname();` allocates memory location for the object. If you have a constructor, then the constructor is called, otherwise default constructor is called.

Comment: That is what all the default constructor do, but my question is, memory in java is allocated after the class comes to its physical existence and when we allocates memory using new operator the memory is allocated for that class, but before that default constructor is called and initialize its instance variables i.e. before the physical class comes into existence and how the memory allocation is actually done in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> **Default constructor is automatically called after an object is created.**

Yes (if the default (no-argument) constructor was called).

> **Can someone explain me the same using a clear example.**

I'm not sure I understand your question to 100 % but no where in the Java Language Specification it says that the constructor should run it's code *before* the memory for the object has been allocated.

This is explained in great detail with an example in [Section 12.5: Creation of new Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5) in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: Sir, it is mentioned in The complete reference of Java that default constructor will initialize the instance variables before new operator allocates memory for that class.

Comment: Where have you read this. Could you provide a URL? You may have misunderstood: The constructor will initialize the members before new *returns* and the references becomes available.

Comment: Sorry sir, I have read in my course book (Complete reference of java) for which I don't have any URL reference.It clearly says that before new allocates memory for the class the default constructor is called and initialize the instance variables.(But instance variable will come into existence after memory is allocated for that class, then how this is possible)

Comment: Above, you quoted the course book as saying "Constructor is automatically called immediately after the object is created, but before the new operator completes."  That is does NOT say "before new allocates memory".  It says "before new completes".  Basically, you have misread / misconstrued what the textbook is saying.  What the textbook is actually saying (based on the quote) is 1) consistent with the JLS, 2) consistent with our answers and 3) logically plausible.

Answer (score 0):

> "...then how default constructor actually do so as the class has not come into physical existence. "

The class is already in memory, the new operator allocates memory space to hold the instance variables and parents instance variables specific to the new instance. But the class had come into physical existence before.